# How can I flatten a deep aggregation in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have documents in an index that look like this:

```json
{
  "foo": null,
  "bars": [
    {
      "baz": "BAZ",
      "qux": null,
      "bears": [
        {
          "fruit": "banana"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to aggregate unique values of `.bars[].bears[].fruit` with counts for each found value. However, I also only want to count these deep values for documents which match certain conditions on `foo`, and for values of `bars[]` that match certain conditions on `baz` and `qux`. I also want to aggregate all documents, ignoring whatever the search query happens to be.

The following query does everything I want to do:

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "global": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "notFoo": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "foo"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "bars": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "bars"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "notValueN": {
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                      "filter": [
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "terms": {
                                  "bars.baz": [
                                    "value1",
                                    "value2",
                                    "value3"
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "terms": {
                                  "bars.qux": [
                                    "value4",
                                    "value5",
                                    "value6"
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ],
                            "minimum_should_match": 1
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "bears": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "bars.bears"
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "rules": {
                          "terms": {
                            "field": "bars.bears.fruit"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query works, but it feels rather large and onerous. In order to get the result I'm looking for out of the response I have to access `.aggregations.global.bars.notValueN.bears.fruit.buckets`. Is there a way to flatten this large query? As it stands, this query is very hard to maintain should any additional conditions need to be introduced later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place where ES supports [object key flattening](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_flat_settings) is in the Cluster settings API. Unfortunately, this strategy **cannot** be used in other parts of the API, including aggregations.

**There are a few other tricks worth mentioning, though.**

#### 1. First off, there's Aggregation Metadata.

Whoever is tasked with post-processing the heavily nested aggregation results will appreciate knowing the target buckets path. You can provide it through an [aggregation metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#add-metadata-to-an-agg) clause:

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "global": {
      "global": {},
      "meta": {
        "accessor_path": "aggs.global.Foo...."  <---
      },
      ...
```

which will return

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "global" : {
      "meta" : {
        "accessor_path" : "aggs.global.Foo..."  <---
      },
      "Foo" : {
```

#### 2. Then, there's Response Filtering

If you had multiple (sub)aggregations enclosed in the same request body, you can reduce the response "bulkiness" through the [`filter_path` URI parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering):

```json
POST your-index/_search/template?filter_path=aggregations.global.meta,aggregations.global.*.*.*.*.*.buckets
{
  "aggs": {
    "global": {
      ...
```

*This may or may not really help you because your agg query seems straightforward & without too many subclauses.*

#### 3. Finally, let's talk about maintainability

When working with reusable queries, Elasticsearch offers the [Search template API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html). You'd construct a script containing a parametrized [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) template and then provide the parameters at query time.

In your particular use case, I'd propose the following:

1. Store the mustache template script:

```json
POST _scripts/nested_bars_query
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": """
      {
        "query": {{#toJson}}raw_search_query{{/toJson}},
        "aggs": {
          "global": {
            "global": {},
            "meta": {
              "accessor_path": "{{accessor_path}}"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "{{notXYZ.agg_name}}": {
                "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                      {
                        "exists": {
                          "field": "{{notXYZ.field_name}}"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "bars": {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "bars"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                      "{{notValueN.agg_name}}": {
                        "filter": {
                          "bool": {
                            "filter": [
                              {
                                "bool": {
                                  "should":  {{#toJson}}notValueN.raw_should_clauses{{/toJson}},
                                  "minimum_should_match": 1
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                          "bears": {
                            "nested": {
                              "path": "bars.bears"
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                              "rules": {
                                "terms": {
                                  "field": "bars.bears.fruit"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    """
  }
}
```

2. Target the `/_search/template/` endpoint with the search template id (`nested_bars_query`). Also, specify the `filter_path` and the metadata `accessor_path` that were discussed above:

```json
POST your-index-name/_search/template?filter_path=aggregations.global.meta,aggregations.global.*.*.*.*.*.buckets
{
  "id": "nested_bars_query",
  "params": {
    "raw_search_query": {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    "accessor_path": "aggs.global.Foo.bars.notValueN.bears.rules.buckets",
    "notXYZ": {
      "agg_name": "Foo",
      "field_name": "foo"
    },
    "notValueN": {
      "agg_name": "notValueN",
      "raw_should_clauses": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "bars.baz": [
              "BAZ",
              "value2",
              "value3"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "bars.qux": [
              "value4",
              "value5",
              "value6"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*You could of course standardize the above by removing the possibility to define custom `agg_name`s etc.*

Should you need to introduce additional conditions later, you can modify the `raw_should_clauses` list inside the `params`.

Comment: Is there any documentation available for `accessor_path`? I can't seem to find anything anywhere.

Comment: Oh, accessor_path is just what I named it. It’s an arbitrary metadata key 

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thank you!

Comment: No prob! Hey, btw there's a whole bunch of concise tips like this in my [recently released ES handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/). One chapter, focused on aggregations, could be particularly relevant to you!